# Why missing space between secret hats in Chromium browser?

Tags: bug, winter-bash

Why I see missing space between secret hats:

[image]

OS: Ubuntu

Browser: Chromium

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing the fallback view for browsers that do not support the CSS Grid spec. Among our supported browsers, Internet Explorer 11 is really the only such browser. Chromium in particular has supported Grid for a long time (and I just checked to confirm it works fine in Chromium on my Mint box). Is it possible you're using a very old version of Chromium?

Comment: Yeah it can be old version of Chromium, as I rmeeber not updating it from long time